# How to split one row into multiple row in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to split one table row into multiple row when calling a js function

This is the table:

```
<table id="tab_calc">
  <tr class="tr_calc">
    <td>Sub Total</td>
    <td>Tax</td>
    <td>Freight</td>
    <td>Insurance</td>
    <td>Discount</td>
    <td>Total</td>  
    <td>Amt Paid</td>     
    <td>Bal Due</td>        
</tr>
```

I want to make it look like this after I call a function:

```
<table id="tab_calc">
 <tr>
    <td>Sub Total</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Tax</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Freight</td>
    <td>Insurance</td>
    <td>Discount</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
    <td>Amt Paid</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>     
    <td>Bal Due</td>        
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: $('table#tab_calc tr:first').after('<tr></tr>');
  $('table#tab_calc tr:first td.pri:gt(3)') 
   .detach() 
   .appendTo('table#tab_calc tr:nth-child(2)');

Comment: i have tried this but it does not meet my requirement

Comment: why don't you manually do the HTML coding? Do you want a generalized function that will split tables `<td>` into particular rows? If so, then you must use a basic logic, like, _'split the 1st `<td>` in one row, split the 2nd and 3rd `<td>` in another single row'_ etc. Do you have some pattern like this to achieve what you want?

Comment: first table is display format. second one is printing format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below code:**

[fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8tto03tx/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tr_calc').replaceWith( $('.tr_calc').html()
   .replace(/<td>/gi, "<tr> <td>")
   .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</td></tr>")
    );
});
```

Comment: I had added fiddler link check it

Comment: ya its working. It split all td into each row. But i need freight, insurance,discount in one row.

Comment: Also after split the table  tag not found in this fiddler

Comment: But i need freight, insurance,discount in one row. how can i do this